# How to install MySQL Workbench Community on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, mysql-workbench, 22.04

The website only has up to 21.10 releases.
Is it safe to just try to download and install the 20.04/21.10 versions or it can damage the system?

*Are there free alternatives for 22.04 except phpMyAdmin?

Comment: If you are comfortable with a query editor, consider BeeKeeper Studio. It's an excellent SQL client that works with MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, and others. This supports SSH tunnelling and works like a charm with local, remote, and cloud-based databases 

Comment: I've tried it (is beautiful by the way) but won't allow edit data in results.

Answer (score 10):

try the snap: `snap install mysql-workbench-community`

You would probably want to set/allow these. I got 'AppArmor'-errors when first trying and those were not set,

- `snap connect mysql-workbench-community:password-manager-service`
- `snap connect mysql-workbench-community:ssh-keys`

Comment: Have some inconsistencies, ie.: the icons won't show correctly.

Comment: the snap version cannot run SQL scripts and has some issues opening folders due to permission errors

Answer (score 0):

Version 8.0.30 is now available on the official site in DEB Package to download and install with apt:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Note: I have detected some crashes, I don't know if it's just me.