# mysql-workbench-community cannot connect though ssh

Tags: permissions, ssh, snap, mysql-workbench

I'm having an issue connecting to a mysql server through a ssh tunel and the app crashes.

I have enabled the ssh-keys in the snap permissions dialog but that does not seem to be helping.

Everytime i try to use the ssh connection i get a 'Could not connect to the SSH Tunnel, The authenticity of host...' popup, which after i confirm (eg. OK) the connection is attempted again with crash.

Is it possible workbench is unable to add the ssh fingerprint to somewhere (as it always asks again)?

I have another connection set up, for which i need to manually open the ssh tunel which seem to be working. (But workbench still crashes, if the ssh tunel is not there).

Just installed a fresh 22.04 Ubuntu

MySQL Workbench 8.0.25 build 788958.

MySQL server: 8.0.28 (on AWS, not that the server seem to be involved?)

Strace of the snap seem to be interesting, and confirming my theory. It crashes right after opening known_hosts first for reading, then writing (both failed?):

```
[pid 102272] close(16)                  = 0
[pid 102272] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/letynsoft/.ssh/known_hosts", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 102272] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 102272] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/letynsoft/.ssh/known_hosts", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 102272] futex(0x7fc3fec9d1e0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
[pid 102272] close(15)                  = 0
[pid 102272] ioctl(2, TCGETS, 0x7fffa0688010) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
[pid 102272] getpid()                   = 102272
[pid 102272] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2329, ...}) = 0
[pid 102272] write(2, "\n(mysql-workbench-bin:102272): g"..., 117
(mysql-workbench-bin:102272): glibmm-ERROR **: 22:52:21.904: 
unhandled exception (type unknown) in signal handler

) = 117
```

follows the last part of `/home/<user>/snap/mysql-workbench-community/9/.mysql/workbench/log/wb.x.log`:

```
22:24:41 [INF][SSHTunnelManager]: Wakeup socket port created: 35105
22:24:41 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Starting tunnel
22:24:41 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one
22:24:41 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to wa4:22
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_connect ssh_connect: libssh 0.9.5 (c) 2003-2019 Aris Adamantiadis, Andreas Schneider and libssh contributors. Distributed under the LGPL, please refer to COPYING file for information about your rights, using threading threads_stdthread
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_socket_connect ssh_socket_connect: Nonblocking connection socket: 16
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_connect ssh_connect: Socket connecting, now waiting for the callbacks to work
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_client_connection_callback ssh_client_connection_callback: SSH server banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_analyze_banner ssh_analyze_banner: Analyzing banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_analyze_banner ssh_analyze_banner: We are talking to an OpenSSH client version: 7.6 (70600)
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_kex_select_methods ssh_kex_select_methods: Negotiated curve25519-sha256,ssh-ed25519,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,none,none,,
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_init_rekey_state ssh_init_rekey_state: Set rekey after 4294967296 blocks
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_init_rekey_state ssh_init_rekey_state: Set rekey after 4294967296 blocks
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_packet_client_curve25519_reply ssh_packet_client_curve25519_reply: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_packet_newkeys ssh_packet_newkeys: Received SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
22:24:41 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_packet_newkeys ssh_packet_newkeys: Signature verified and valid
22:26:42 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to wa4:22
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_connect ssh_connect: libssh 0.9.5 (c) 2003-2019 Aris Adamantiadis, Andreas Schneider and libssh contributors. Distributed under the LGPL, please refer to COPYING file for information about your rights, using threading threads_stdthread
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_socket_connect ssh_socket_connect: Nonblocking connection socket: 16
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_connect ssh_connect: Socket connecting, now waiting for the callbacks to work
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_client_connection_callback ssh_client_connection_callback: SSH server banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_analyze_banner ssh_analyze_banner: Analyzing banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_analyze_banner ssh_analyze_banner: We are talking to an OpenSSH client version: 7.6 (70600)
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_kex_select_methods ssh_kex_select_methods: Negotiated curve25519-sha256,ssh-ed25519,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,none,none,,
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_init_rekey_state ssh_init_rekey_state: Set rekey after 4294967296 blocks
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_init_rekey_state ssh_init_rekey_state: Set rekey after 4294967296 blocks
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_packet_client_curve25519_reply ssh_packet_client_curve25519_reply: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_packet_newkeys ssh_packet_newkeys: Received SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
22:26:42 [INF][      SSHCommon]: libssh: ssh_packet_newkeys ssh_packet_newkeys: Signature verified and valid
```

How do i enable this snap to access the `.ssh/known_hosts` ?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is there really no way to 'add' a file for access by snap by user? Are snaps basicaly unusable? I have never had much luck with them

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403713/132783

Basically.

```
snap connect mysql-workbench-community:password-manager-service
snap connect mysql-workbench-community:ssh-keys
```